# Convert old codebase (List/Vector iterator not dereferencable)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have an old codebase which I would like to compile on vs2012, now after removing lots of legacy headers I ended up with a version that compiles and runs properly but it crashes with (List iterator not dereferencable) errors. I found out this is only happens on .erase calls which operate on a list or vector. The original codebase uses vs2003.net.

Now the question is, I know how to convert them but the problem is that there is over 400 places where this error would occur and I just cannot convert all of that manually. Does anyone know of some method/hack to make the new vector classes compatable with the old coding ways? STLPort or some custom STL or some defines or something?

Comment: could you give an before-and-after example of such a function call that you refactored?